# How to calculate the variance of linear prediction parameters?

Tags: linear-programming

I'm using [linear prediction with singular value decomposition](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TASSP.1982.1163927) (LPSVD) to analyze signals that are damped sinusoids. If my understanding of the theory of linear prediction is correct (and it may not be) then LPSVD is actually doing a linear least squares fit. If this is correct then I should be able to calculate the estimated variance in the model parameters in a way similar to a simple linear regression of one variable.

Can anyone suggest a reference that might have useful information? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the best way to calculate the variance on the parameters returned by the LPSVD algorithm is to use the [Cramér-Rao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) bound as the estimate. If anyone has a more elegant solution I'd like to hear it.